# Write a program that prompts user to enter two points (work included)

Tags: java

Write a program that prompts user to enter two points (x1,y1) and (x2, y2) and display the distance between them. The formula for computing distance is: square root of(x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2

This is what I have:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TwoPoints {
    private static double x;
    private static double distance;

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter first two points (x1,y1) :");
        double x1 = input.nextDouble();
        double y1 = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.print("Enter second two points (x2,y2) :");
        double x2 = input.nextDouble();
        double y2 = input.nextDouble();
        x = ((x2 - x1) * (x2 - x1) + (y2 - y1) * (y2 - y1));


        distance = Math.sqrt(x);
        System.out.print("The distance of the two points is " + distance);
```

However:

I keep getting the following error:

```
Enter first two points (x1,y1) :4,2
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:909)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2456)
at TwoPoints.main(TwoPoints.java:23)

Java Result: 1

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 4 seconds)
```

Please help. Thanks

Comment: Or change your input to expect , as a delimiter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The explanation is in the second sentence of the [Scanner javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html):

> A Scanner breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern, which by default matches whitespace.

A comma is not a white space, and `,2` is not a valid double.

Comment: So try `4 2` instead of `4,2`.

Comment: Use `System.out.println()` instead of `System.out.print()`.

Answer (score 0):

4 (enter) 2 (enter) for (two) integers

or 4.2 (with dot) if you want real number

Comment: Yes, it looks like you need to press enter between entering each point.

Answer (score 0):

You are separating the values with a comma, which breaks the Scanner class. Try this, it uses BufferedReader and split() to separate the comma separated values:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    System.out.print("Enter first coordinates: ");
    String[] firstCoords = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        System.in)).readLine().split(",");
    double x1 = Double.valueOf(firstCoords[0]);
    double y1 = Double.valueOf(firstCoords[1]);

    System.out.print("Enter second coordinates: ");
    String[] secondCoords = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)).readLine().split(",");
    double x2 = Double.valueOf(secondCoords[0]);
    double y2 = Double.valueOf(secondCoords[1]);

    double result = Math.sqrt(((x2-x1)*(x2-x1)+(y2-y1)*(y2-y1)));
    System.out.println(String.valueOf(result));
    }
```

Output:

```
Enter first coordinates: 6,7
Enter second coordinates: 0,0
9.219544457292887
```